# Quicker way to hardening with CIS Benchmark on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, security, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I'm hardening new Windows 2016 servers manually with CIS Benchmark

Since I've got a couple of 'em and can't copy/duplicate the VM for some "reasons". I need to extract the secpol and copy it on another server with *M̺̬̘á̗̯̥̜̺g̮̼̮̪̰͘i̸͙̦̬̱̲͍̭c͕̳̭̠̪̮*.

Since I'm no magician I first figurred out that I could extract it with :

```
secedit /export /cfg c:\secpol.cfg
```

Then I got confuse avout how I could import it on my new machine

I foud this here on stack:

```
secedit /configure /db c:\windows\security\local.sdb /cfg c:\secpol.cfg /areas SECURITYPOLICY
rm -force c:\secpol.cfg -confirm:$false
```

However the folder does not hold the local.sdb is there something I'm missing?

** **If you guys have better ways of doing it I'm all ears!** **